# Virtual Disk Mounting Win7 Virtual disk sdk

Tags: windows-7, vhd, virtual-disk

I write a program in C++ using Windows 7 SDK, virtual disk functions.
When we mount an virtual disk, how can we get which letter Windows assigned to this new disk?